# R programming, how to group by range

Tags: r, group-by, range

my data is

```
a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)  
b=c(10.55 ,11.62, 15.24, 13.65, 17.66, 19.51, 12.54, 16.54, 18.54, 15.35)  
c=c(a, b, c, a, c, b, a, a, c, d )  
df=data.frame(a, b, c)
```

How to make group by range?
range is 3 groups ((10.55, 15.35], (15.35, 17.66], (17.66, 19.51])
and analysis for freqency C.

thanks

Comment: See `?cut` - it does exactly what you want I believe.

Comment: Make sure your example data actually works (it doesn't).

Comment: Where should 10.55 be included? Also what is c?? you are concatenating c yet it has not been predefined.. `c(a, b, c, a, c, b, a, a, c, d ) ` what is the c inside the vector?

Comment: Lol recursively defining `c` inside `c(...)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cut2` in `Hmisc` package:

```
library(Hmisc)

Otput <- cut2(df$a, c(10.55, 15.35,17.66))
```

Please make your example reproducible and we can test the output.